# CSS FlexBox issue

Tags: css, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

Can someone tell me how I can reduce width automatically on new child,

[image]

```js
const Container = styled(View)(
  {
    padding: 3,
    flex: 1,
    minHeight: "50%",
    minWidth: 300,
  },
  variant({
    prop: "type",
    variants: {
      one: { flex: "1 0 100%", alignSelf: "stretch" },
      two: { flex: "1 0 50%", width: "50%" },
      three: { flex: "1 0 33%", width: "33%" },
    },
  })
);
```

Comment: `flex-grow: 1` will do that (the single item on the second row has no siblings to restrict its expansion). It's a common problem. Check the duplicates for solutions.

Comment: duplicates ? and do i need to add flexGrow in items or grid , sorry I am pretty new in flexbox

Comment: The duplicates contain various solutions to the problem in your question. Go through them. Let me know if you have any questions.